# A scheme whose underlying space is the product of the underlying spaces of schemes

Tags: gn.general-topology, schemes

We [know](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0907) that the product of two spectral topological spaces is spectral.

- If $X$ is the underlying space of the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}[x]$, what is a simple example of an affine scheme whose underlying space is $X\times X$?
- If $X$ is the underlying space of the scheme $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}[x]$, what is a simple example of an affine scheme whose underlying space is $X\times X$?

Comment: btw, your link shows you could associate a scheme in principle, can you associate a scheme functorially? Kind of modified product of schemes?

Comment: @schematic_boi Meta discussion that may be relevant: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-new-users/